# How to build project WAR file and it's dependencies in TAR/ZIP file

Tags: maven

I am new to Maven and know the basic concepts of Maven. I got a requirment to work on mavenizing multiple projects which uses most of common/same jars.

I was asked to build a TAR/ZIP file that contains all the jars and build WAR file for each project with out jars. So that Project (WAR) can use jars present in TAR/ZIP file.

finally after build, TAR/ZIP file needs to be deployed on server forst and later WAR file. so that, in run time WAR can have refrence to jars.

Can anyone please help me in this ?

Actually this structure will reduce size of WAR files as we are keeping these jars in single TAR/ZIP file and deploying it in tomcat server.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. The war file already contains all its dependencies inside `WEB-INF/lib`, so which jar are you talking about? What is your project structure?

Comment: I am dealing with 3 projects that are developed based on spring & Hibernate. at present we are including these jars under WEB-INF/lib for each WAR file. 
But I want these jars to be in single location and want to build all these jars together in ZIP/TAR format. So that I can simply deploy this TAR/ZIP file which reduces the size of my WAR files.